# fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Inva

Tags: git, openshift, business-process-management

while cloning repositories from bpm suite installed in Openshift.I am getting the following git error.

**fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Inva**

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is generally seen when using an SSH URL (like `git@aserver:arepo`)

The usual cause is, on the git repository hosting server side, a .profile or `.bashrc` which includes some `echo`: see [Git FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#protocol_error:_bad_line_length_character)

> It likely means you have some extraneous characters, info message or something upon logging into ssh in command mode.

To test this, do:

```
ssh -T user@git.example.com echo testing commands
```

> You should only see testing commands returned. If there are any other characters, you should examine your dot shell `rc` file to find any `echo` or other commands that may produce output.

In your case, for Openshift, [consider one of the common commands](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-remote-connection.html#common-commands):

rhc ssh ls

Check if the `ls` is polluted by any other output.

Comment: I am getting: 
`
$ ssh git@240.162.0.163 
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
This account is currently not available.
Connection to 240.162.0.163 closed.
`

Comment: @TheoBouwman First use `ssh -T ...` to avoid the "`PTY allocation request failed `". Second, to you have a `git` remote user on 240.162.0.163?

Comment: yes I have git as remote user. But it couldn't acces /etc/gitea so I just chmod -R 777 /etc/gitea

Comment: @TheoBouwman OK. Does it work now that you did the chmod?

Comment: Yes, but i dont think its the best way to solve this issue

Comment: @TheoBouwman I agree. You should ask a separate question, referencing that 7 years old answer.