# fatal: Protocol Error: bad line length : this over Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I would like to ask a question regarding Jenkins, as I am getting this error while Jenkins going to fetch sub module of the repository, it was running properly but somehow it will getting this kind of error. I have tried to compile on the local system and it was working perfectly but not over Jenkins. My repository is one the git server and we are using Gerrit trigger plugin on the Jenkins. Here, I am using a windows system for Jenkins. can anyone help me in this where am I getting wrong?

> git submodule update --init --recursive Gateway/host/SDK # timeout=50
>   11:21:28 hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git submodule update --init --recursive Gateway/host/SDK" returned status code 1:
>   11:21:28 stdout: 
>   11:21:28 stderr: Cloning into 'E:/Jenkins/workspace/Nebulae/HVAC_Windows/Gateway/host/SDK/components/nbl-mib/nbl-mib-service'...
>   11:21:28 fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: This
>   11:21:28 fatal: clone of 'ssh://gitolite@192.168.0.206/nebulae/nbl-mib-service.git' into submodule path 'E:/Jenkins/workspace/Nebulae/HVAC_Windows/Gateway/host/SDK/components/nbl-mib/nbl-mib-service' failed
>   11:21:28 Failed to clone 'components/nbl-mib/nbl-mib-service'. Retry scheduled
>   11:21:28 Cloning into 'E:/Jenkins/workspace/Nebulae/HVAC_Windows/Gateway/host/SDK/components/nbl-mib/nbl-mib-service'...
>   11:21:28 fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: This
>   11:21:28 fatal: clone of 'ssh://gitolite@192.168.0.206/nebulae/nbl-mib-service.git' into submodule path 'E:/Jenkins/workspace/Nebulae/HVAC_Windows/Gateway/host/SDK/components/nbl-mib/nbl-mib-service' failed
>   11:21:28 Failed to clone 'components/nbl-mib/nbl-mib-service' a second time, aborting
>   11:21:28 Failed to recurse into submodule path 'Gateway/host/SDK'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Inva](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32644342/fatal-protocol-error-bad-line-length-character-inva)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+protocol+error%3A+bad+line+length