# Gitea cannot clone

Tags: git, gitea

I have installed Gitea on a LXC container and added my ssh key through the UI.

But when I do `git clone git@240.162.0.163:theo/test-repo.git` I will get the following error:

```
Cloning into 'test-repo'...
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: This
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32645891/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fatal%3A+protocol+error%3A+bad+line+length+character

Comment: Start debugging with `ssh git@240.162.0.163`

Answer (score 0):

I have seen [this before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17546706/6309) whenever your remote user `profile`/`.bashrc` prints data, instead of being silent.

If, for instance, `ssh git@240.162.0.163 pwd` returns anything else than the path working directory on the remote machine, Git would be in trouble, as it would not interpret correctly the output of its SSH query when cloning the remote repository.